# Ethernet and Wifi Not Working After installing HWE Kernel

Tags: networking, dell

I have a Dell precision 5520 laptop. I had recently installed xubuntu 16.04.5 on it and everything was working fine out of the box. I wanted to change some settings with the track pad and found this [tutorial](https://www.dell.com/support/article/hk/en/hkbsd1/sln308258/precision-xps-ubuntu-general-touchpad-mouse-issue-fix?lang=en) from Dell on how to change it. I was following it and after installing the HWE kernel and rebooting all my networking devices don't connect. I'm not great a Linux and I don't know what to do after ip link set XXX up didn't work. I don't wanna reinstall and have to install all my programs again.

rfkill list all

```
0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
4: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

lshw -C network

```
*-network DISABLED      
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 32
       serial: 54:13:79:54:15:ef
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.15.0-32-generic firmware=WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00079-QCARMSWPZ-1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:139 memory:ed200000-ed3fffff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: enxa44cc8abc98b
       serial: a4:4c:c8:ab:c9:8b
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.09.9 duplex=full link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
```

dmesg | grep ath10k

```
[    8.079213] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    8.080706] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: pci irq msi oper_irq_mode 2 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    8.381995] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/pre-cal-pci-0000:02:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    8.382002] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:02:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    8.390356] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 target 0x05030000 chip_id 0x00340aff sub 1028:0310
[    8.390358] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[    8.390786] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00079-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 6 features wowlan,ignore-otp crc32 fd869beb
[    8.481819] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: board_file api 2 bmi_id N/A crc32 20d869c3
[    9.098325] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Unknown eventid: 118809
[    9.101254] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Unknown eventid: 90118
[    9.101956] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: htt-ver 3.47 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
[    9.195329] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
```

lsb-release -a

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Firmware Version --- 4.15.0-32-generic

I hope this is enough information to get an idea of what going on